# Django - Form not saving when submitted

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Good afternoon all,

One of my form does not seem to save when submitted. I cannot see why, in particular as I have a similar form working just fine using the same code.

For some reason it work just fine using the admin panel.

My assumption is that I am missing something that tells the form it needs to be saved. But cannot find what.

Any ideas?

**Models**

```
RATING=(
    (1,'1'),
    (2,'2'),
    (3,'3'),
    (4,'4'),
    (5,'5'),
)
class ProductReview(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product=models.ForeignKey(Product,related_name="comments", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    review_text=models.TextField(max_length=250)
    review_rating=models.IntegerField(choices=RATING,max_length=150, default=0)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**Views**

```
def add_review(request, product_id):
    product = Product.objects.get(pk=product_id)
    form = ReviewAdd(request.POST or None, instance=product) #instance=product (populate field with existing information)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('product')
    return render(request, 'main/add_review.html',{'form':form})
```

**URL**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
...
path('product/add_review/<product_id>', views.add_review,name="add_review"),
]
```

**Forms**

```
class ReviewAdd(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ProductReview
        fields = ('review_text', 'review_rating')
        labels ={
            'review_text': '',
            'review_rating': '',
                }

        widgets = {
                    'review_text': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Enter Review'}),
                    }
```

**Admin**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Venue, User, Product, ProductReview
from django.urls import path


admin.site.register(User)
admin.site.register(ProductReview)


class ProductReview(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display=['user','product','review_text','get_review_rating']
```

HTML Page

```
{% extends 'main/base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block title %} 
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <center>
        <h1>Add ReviewTo Database</h1>
        <br/><br/>
        
        {% if submitted %}
            Success!
        {% else %}
                <form action="" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form|crispy }}
                <input type="Submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-secondary">
                </form>
        {% endif %}
    </center>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: 2 questions, 1. it throws you some error? 2. When you submit, does it redirects you to your path 'product' or does it shows you the form again?

Comment: Hi there! It takes me back to the product page, no error message.

Comment: Ok, inside the if form.is_valid(), do a new_instance = form.save(), and next line print(new_instance), in terminal will show you the new instance with its id, if it does that, everything is working fine, if not printing anything, the form somewhere is not valid, and you can print form.errors just before return, outside the if block

Comment: Thanks! It prints the product name (product id), but not the comment or the associated rating. I have also tried through the admin panel (adding a comment), when I do this, the product id is also printed, but not the comment, even the comment is definitely added to the data base.

Comment: It just printing the str representation, if you want to see every data, print new_instance.__dict__ and review it, posting my suggest answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I detect 2 fixes

On your url, the parameter product_id might need the type of data it will going to receive

```
path('product/add_review/<int:product_id>', views.add_review,name="add_review"),
```

And in your view, you are sending an instance, and no data for a new rating.
In your view:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404


@login_required
def add_review(request, product_id):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=product_id)
    form = ReviewAdd(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        new_rating = form.save(commit=False)
        new_rating.product = product
        new_rating.user = request.user
        new_rating.save()
        return redirect('product')
    return render(request, 'main/add_review.html',{'form':form})
```

Comment: It didnt seem to correct the problem. But thank you very much for trying!

Comment: Just wanted to say, I retried your proposed solution and it actually worke this time. I removed "new_rating.user = request.user" and everything suddently functionned! So thanks :)